# Axis2 empty array

Tags: java, apache-axis

I recive null insted of empty array on the client side when my POJO axis2 method returns empty array. I understand that the problem is in WSDL.

Is there is any way to configure axis2 to generate valid WSDL?
I create axis2 service programmatically:

```
ConfigurationContext context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);

Map<String, MessageReceiver> mrMap = new HashMap<String, MessageReceiver>();
mrMap.put("http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-only", RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.class.newInstance());
mrMap.put("http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl/in-out",  RPCMessageReceiver.class.newInstance());

AxisService service = AxisService.createService(...);
context.getAxisConfiguration().addService(service);
SimpleHTTPServer server = new SimpleHTTPServer(context, port);

server.start();
```

And anybody can give example of custom SchemaGenerator for Axis2 Services?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but let me answer this question. I think you did not create object inside your POJO. You might have just declared its reference. Create an object for it. Then it will show empty instead of `null` in the response.